# SQL Server 2014 - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'tran'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I am trying to install a stored procedures. When I run the query I get Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'tran'

The 'tran' keyword is used in `dump tran master with no_log`

It would be helpful if anyone help me overcome this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a syntax error because `TRAN` isn't a SQL keyword and isn't valid for the syntax of `DUMP`. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187315(v=sql.90).aspx. To use `DUMP` properly, it's either `DUMP DATABASE` or `DUMP TRANSACTION`

Note that per the above link, `DUMP` is flagged as deprecated and only exists for backwards compatibility. It will go away in the future. You should be using `BACKUP` (probably `BACKUP LOG` in this case) instead.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.!

Answer (score 2):

From some SQL Server 2005 documentation on [DUMP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187315(v=sql.90).aspx), I found the following:

> The DUMP statement is included for backward compatibility. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Instead, use **BACKUP**.

I bet that `DUMP` has already been removed from SQL Server 2014.